# storing json output in bash from cloudfromation

Tags: json, bash, amazon-web-services, scripting, amazon-ecs

I am using aws ecs query to get list of properties being used by the current running task.

command -
`cft = "aws ecs describe-tasks --cluster arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:4984314772:cluster/secrets --tasks arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:4984314772:task/secrets/86855757eec4487f9d4475a1f7c4cb0b`

I am storing this in an output variable

output= $( eval $cft)

Output:

```
    "tasks": [
        {
            "attachments": [
                {
                    "id": "da8a1312-8278-46d5-8e3b-6b6a1d96f820",
                    "type": "ElasticNetworkInterface",
                    "status": "ATTACHED",
                    "details": [
                        {
                            "name": "subnetId",
                            "value": "subnet-0a151f2eb959ad4"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "networkInterfaceId",
                            "value": "eni-081948e3666253f"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "macAddress",
                            "value": "02:2a:9i:5c:4a:77"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "privateDnsName",
                            "value": "ip-172-56-17-177.us-west-2.compute.internal"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "privateIPv4Address",
                            "value": "172.56.17.177"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "availabilityZone": "us-west-2a",
            "clusterArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:4984314772:cluster/secrets",
            "containers": [
                {
                    "taskArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:4984314772:task/secrets/86855757eec4487f9d4475a1f7c4cb0b",
                    "name": "nginx",
                    "image": "nginx",
                    "lastStatus": "PENDING",
                    "networkInterfaces": [
                        {
                            "attachmentId": "da8a1312-8278-46d5-6b6a1d96f820",
                            "privateIpv4Address": "172.31.17.176"
                        }
                    ],
                    "healthStatus": "UNKNOWN",
                    "cpu": "0"
                }
            ],
            "cpu": "256",
            "createdAt": "2020-12-10T18:00:16.320000+05:30",
            "desiredStatus": "RUNNING",
            "group": "family:nginx",
            "healthStatus": "UNKNOWN",
            "lastStatus": "PENDING",
            "launchType": "FARGATE",
            "memory": "512",
            "overrides": {
                "containerOverrides": [
                    {
                        "name": "nginx"
                    }
                ],
                "inferenceAcceleratorOverrides": []
            },
            "platformVersion": "1.4.0",
            "tags": [],
            "taskArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:4984314772:task/secrets/86855757eec4487f9d4475a1f7c4cb0b",
            "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:4984314772:task-definition/nginx:17",
            "version": 2
        }
    ],
    "failures": []
}
```

now if do an echo of $output.tasks[0].containers[0]  nothing happens it prints the entire thing again, i want to store the result in output variable and refer different parameter like we do in json format.

Comment: Why are you using the evil `eval` at all when you could capture the command output with `output=$(aws ecs describe-tasks --cluster arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:4984314772:cluster/secrets --tasks arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:4984314772:task/secrets/86855757eec4487f9d4475a1f7c4cb0b)`?

Comment: Yeah the reason i am using eval is, in my main bash script i am using that in different context, i am also using the one stated above, i am storing the output in a variable now i need to access the json body, how do i do that.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a json parser such as jq and so:

```
eval $cft | jq '.tasks[].containers[]'
```

To avoid using eval you could simple pipe the aws command into jq and so:

```
aws ecs describe-tasks --cluster arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:4984314772:cluster/secrets --tasks arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:4984314772:task/secrets/86855757eec4487f9d4475a1f7c4cb0b | jq '.tasks[].containers[]'
```

or:

```
cft=$(aws ecs describe-tasks --cluster arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:4984314772:cluster/secrets --tasks arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:4984314772:task/secrets/86855757eec4487f9d4475a1f7c4cb0b | jq '.tasks[].containers[]')

echo $cft | jq '.tasks[].containers[]'
```

Comment: This solution helps me in querying the ECS container image, but i want to store the result in a single variable and access other various properties such as launchtype, created_at. Rather than querying again, i just want to pull the value from the stored variable.  

This below also achieves the same

`aws ecs describe-tasks --cluster arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:4984314772:cluster/secrets --tasks arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:4984314772:task/secrets/faee1ff0b633481e8d12abfb96b87f5f --query "tasks[*].containers[*]"`

Comment: You will need to change the is statement accordingly then.

Comment: I just want to store the output in a variable and pick different parameters out of them such as launchtype, createdat etc. Rather than querying it everytime, i just want to query the variable.